# Reset drop down after selecting new value

Tags: excel, vba, developer-tools

whats wrong with the code i posted

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 100


If Target.Address = "$C$i" Then


Range("Di:EI") = " "

End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` is a variable, but you are not using it as such in your code.

These two lines should look like this:

```
If Target.Address = "$C$" & i Then


Range("D" & i & ":E" & i) = " "
```

that way the result string uses the value of `i` instead of the letter `i`.

I'm also assuming you meant `Ei` instead of `EI` (which is also wrong) so I fixed that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim i As Long
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For i = 1 To 100
            If Target.Address = "$C$" & i Then
                Range("D" & i & ":E" & i) = " "
            End If
        Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a  lot , for your fedex reply , its working as expected